# Why am I getting this?

Tags: support

So I wanted to ask a question and I got this error. I didn't ask a question in the previous 90 minutes.

[image: failed to load image]

What I do?

Comment: You are not you.

Comment: @MartinJames - ??

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, I think he means it's not me who asked the previous question, it's one of my schoolmates with whom I share the network with.